How to configure STM32 UART TX to generate a decodable signal?
I am trying to transmit data from an STM32F411 (blackpill) via UART, and am having trouble generating a signal that works.
The problem is that, when configured with the default GPIO settings, the UART TX signal is low when not sending data, and a logic analyser (PulseView) hooked up to the signal fails to decode the first few transmitted characters due to the (low) start bit not triggering a transition from high to low. The logic analyser considers the first transition from high to low to be the start bit, so starts parsing the stream halfway through the first byte.
After one or more bytes having been transmitted, the logic analyser is able to decode bytes as it syncs up with the actual start bits.

(In this trace, after the first 5 failed bytes, decoding is successful ('o' onwards)). Message should start with "note on"
I can get the logic level of the TX pin to be high when not transmitting if I configure it as open drain with pull-up. With this setting, the first start bit results in a transition from high to low, and PulseView can successfully decode the transmitted bytes starting with the first one.
However although this works when attached to the logic analyzer, it doesn't work with e.g. a USB to serial cable or an oscilloscope connected to the pin - the signal isn't pulled-up fast enough resulting in a signal that can't be decoded successfully.
To get an idea of the kind of signal I need to generate I had a look at the output from the TX pin of a USB-to-serial (TTL 3.3v) cable and that's high when it's not transmitting.
On the STM32, UART settings are default (8bits no parity 1 stop bit), and in PulseView settings are also default, and the same.

If it does not work when configured as open-drain output, why do you do that instead of configuring it as normal output?

It works with the logic analyser when configured open drain with pull up, but doesn't generate a good signal when attached to an oscilloscope or serial usb cable, as mentioned in the question.It doesn't work when gpio settings are default, for the reason explained in the question.

Show. how exactly do you configure UART and handle transmission. If done properly, after transmitter is enabled, it should generate one IDLE frame before transmitting the first frame. You can also always add an external or enable internal pullup, even if the pin is configured as push-pull in GPIOx_OTYPER.
